# Indexes as Ints in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code which I've commented:

```
func hash (s:String) -> Int {
    var z = 19
    let key = "abcdefghijk"
    for var i = 0; i < s.characters.count; i++ {
        let index = s.startIndex.advancedBy(i)
        let char = s[index]

        if let f = key.characters.indexOf(char) {
            print(f) //This outputs the number I want to use in the next line, but as String.CharacterView.Index, not an Int
            z = (z * f) //obviously this won't work 
        }
        // So instead we try this:
        z = z * s.startIndex.distanceTo(key.characters.indexOf(char)!))
        // It works for the first few characters then I get "fatal error: can not increment endIndex" and a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
    }
    return z
}
```

I'm struggling to use Swift `String` to find the index I want to use as an `Int` in some kind of a hash function. In case it isn't clear:

User inputs a string, the function iterates through each character, finding that character in the `key` and then takes the index of that character in `key` and multiplies it to the existing `z` counter.

I get the results I want but only in the wrong type which doesn't let me convert to Int. Anyone know how?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have some special requirements about returning hash value? if not, i suggest you  func hash(s:String)->Int { return s.hashValue } It is free, build-in and at least, but not last, produced hashValue meets some 'apple standards'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f = key.characters.indexOf(char)` is an index into the characters
of `key`, therefore you have to compute the distance to the start index of `key`, not `s`:

```
z = z * key.startIndex.distanceTo(key.characters.indexOf(char)!))
```

which you can move back to your `if-let` block:

```
    if let f = key.characters.indexOf(char) {
        z = z * key.startIndex.distanceTo(f)
    }
```

You also might want to use the [overflow operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) `&*`

```
    if let f = key.characters.indexOf(char) {
        z = z &* key.startIndex.distanceTo(f)
    }
```

otherwise the application will crash if the result of the 
multiplication does not fit into an `Int`.

---

Generally, the indexes of a Swift `String` can only be used 
with the *same* string (regardless of string length), as the following
example demonstrates:

```
let s1 = "abc"
let i1 = s1.characters.indexOf("b")!
print(i1) // 1

let s2 = "abc"
print(s2.characters.count) // 6

let d2 = s2.startIndex.distanceTo(i1) // fatal error: can not increment endIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make your key into an array of `Character`s, then `indexOf` will return the `Int` you need:

```
func hash (s:String) -> Int {
    var z = 19
    let key = Array("abcdefghijk".characters)
    for char in s.characters {
        if let f = key.indexOf(char) {
            print(f)
            z = (z &* (f + 1))
        }
    }
    return z
}
```

Also, if your character is the first index in the key you will get a value of `0` which will make your hash value `0`, so I've added `1` to `f`.  I also incorporated `&*` as suggested by @MartinR to prevent `Int` *overflow*.

Comment: Nice answer! I up voted it. Still this function will produce for strings longer that say X characters 0. Why not simply use build-in hashValue? String conforms to Hashable as well.

Answer (score -1):

First, don't use forced unwrap as you can end up easily crashing your app (as it seems it already happened).

Second, you already test for the validity of `key.characters.indexOf(char)`, you can place the `z` computation within the `if-let`:

```
z = z * s.startIndex.distanceTo(f)
```

What happens with your code is that the `hash()` function crashes as soon as it encounters a character beyond `k`, so you should also add all possible characters to `key`.